# Is white residue on a mobile phone water damage indication

Tags: capacitor

I have bought a Samsung Galaxy S4 mini that burnt from the charging point. When sent to get repaired, they told me it was water damage. Illustrating in a picture some white residue circling a black rectangle capacitor of some sort. Can anything else cause this residue to appear?

Comment: A good high quality close-up photograph of the component and residue in question is needed.

Comment: Most repair centers always tell you there is water damage if they have to put effort in a warranty claim.

Answer (score 4):

White residue can appear on electronics from a variety of sources:

- Water damage: minerals and other contaminants in water leave a white powder or film once the liquid evaporates
- Battery chemistry: Batteries can leak, resulting in a white powdery residue of potassium carbonate (from leaking potassium hydroxide).
- PCB manufacturing processes: No-clean flux can leave a white residue
- Silicone heatsink compound: Power transistors, rectifiers, and other components attached to heatsinks usually have a silicone compound which aids transfer of heat from the component to the heatsink. Often this is a white gel-like substance, but can sometimes appear more dry and powdery

In the case of your phone, it's most likely to be water damage, but a macro photo would be helpful to make any more accurate assessment.